# XCode: Additional localization of only one button

Tags: xcode, string, user-interface, button, localized

After a long long time, I added another button to my apps dialog. I had localized strings implemented. So I found a similar one like

```
/* Class = "NSButtonCell"; title = "Keep number"; ObjectID = "2yE-rM-5Sn"; */
"2yE-rM-5Sn.title" = "Nicht umnumerieren";
```

in file "Main.strings (German)". Unfortunately I forget, how I got there. I did the entire translation in one step in one night. Now I only need to get one new translation for the newly added button. 
Any hint how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your project name (1.), in my case Timebooking. Maybe the application is selected instead in Targets and you have more options but not localization. Then select Use Base Localization (2.). It should create the English Main.strings file when you add English. There you can add the proper translation. HTH.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had to use french, becuase I already had english in use.

Comment: Glad it helped. :-) I had a similar issue where I had buttons and labels in norwegian and added english and danish.